code to solve square roots always results in 0
I'm trying to write a code in RISC-V32 that solves square root with user input, but the result is always 0.
.data
prompt: .string "Enter any number to get the square root: "
format_double: .string "%.2lf\n"
input: .float 0.0
result: .double 0.0
.text
main:
# Print prompt
la  a0, prompt       # Load the address of the prompt string
li  a7, 4            # Load the syscall number to print string
ecall                # Execute the syscall
# Read user input
li  a0, 0            # Load a0 with 0 (standard input)
la  a1, input        # Load the address of the input variable
li  a7, 6            # Load the syscall number to read a float
ecall                # Execute the syscall to read the float input

# Load the float value into register f10
flw  f10, 0(a1)      # Load the float from memory into register f10

# Calculate the square root
fsqrt.d f10, f10     # Calculate the square root of f10 (double precision)

# Convert the double to string and print
li  a0, 2            # Load the syscall number to print a double
li  a7, 2            # Load the syscall number to print a double
ecall                # Execute the syscall to print the double

# Exit the program
li  a7, 10           # Load the syscall number to exit
ecall                # Execute the syscall

I don't know how to fix it. I supose that my mistake is on the syscalls but I don't really know how it works. Can you guys help me?
